# Start activity in another app with restricting receiving app to have same signature

Tags: android, permissions, startactivityforresult

I have two apps A and B. At some point A calls startActivityForResult() with Intent that points to activity in B (using "action" attribute). Both apps will be downloaded from Google Play and will be signed with the same certificate.

Since some sensitive information will be exchanged in the Intent's data I want to prevent a bad actor from replacing app B and installing his own version with same package name and action attribute which will receive the control from app A when startActivityForResult() is called.

I know how to ensure that app B is called only from app A (custom permission) but I was wondering, is there a way to ensure that when app A class startActivityForResult() that only my app B will receive the Intent?

Comment: what if both - app a and b will be custom-signed with same signture?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko You mean the bad actor to replace both apps?

Comment: yes. Sorry, I don't have a solution for the question itself...

Comment: Only thing I could suggest - don;t expect any data to be secure (except maibe only if it has been encrypted not on Android device, but on the server for example)

Comment: @tynn you mean something like app A starts B without data, app B gets the data via content provider in A?

Comment: Yes, that would be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

"installing his own version with same package name"

although playstore allows for apps to have duplicate names it enforces the uniqueness of any app package name. so this shouldnt happen.

moreover, you can use a custom action attribute name for starting B .

hope this is helpful for now .

Comment: Google play will enforce it, but what if the bad guy just installs an APK...